# Laravel : Model Relations between 3 tables

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

i have 3 tables  `shops` ,  `business_categories`  , `shop_categories`  as below

1. Business Categories holds has all the categories
2. Shop has shops data
3. Shop categories has ids for shops and businiess categories which are assigned to shop

I need to list the category names with shop listing. i am able to get categories but not sure how can i relate 3rd table

in my `Shop Model`

```
 public function shopCategories(){
    return $this->belongsTo(ShopCategory::class,'shop_id','shop_id');
 }
```

In my controller

```
Shop::with('shopCategories')->get()
```

this returns me shops and data from `shop_categories` table but i am not sure how can i relate `shop_categories` to `business_categories` table

Edit ::

**business_categories**

[image]

**shop_categories**

[image]

**shop**

[image]

Comment: you can define relation in Shop category model for business category and use it in your shop model via Shop  category.

Comment: @DevsiOdedra  could you please post it  as an answer ? that would help ..

Comment: Look at this document method: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: add a relationship function of business_categories in your ShopCategory model and in with() use like this with('shopCategories.your_another_relationship_name')

Comment: what should it be i am not sure about that ?  @sandipbharadva

Answer (score 2):

basically you have classic [Many-To-Many](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relation between `Shop` and `BusinessCategory` models (each shop can have many categories and category can have many shops), so

1. in table **shop_categories** you don't need field `shop_category_id` as intermidiate tables mostly don't use primary keys
2. defining standard many-to-many relation

```php
//Shop model
public function categories() {
  return $this->belongsToMany(BusinessCategory::class, 'shop_categories', 'business_category_id', 'shop_id');
}

//BusinessCategory model
public function shops() {
  return $this->belongsToMany(Shop::class, 'shop_categories', 'shop_id', 'business_category_id');
}
```

3. now when relation is set in controller you may do

```php
$categoriesWithShops = BusinessCategory::with('shops')->get();
```

and get desired categories with shops listing

this way don't makes you to drop `ShopCategory` model and stop using it (if needed), but explores some beautiful things like `sync`, `toggle` etc for defined relation

Answer (score 0):

Use laravel [Has Many Through](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relation model:

In your shop categories model:

```
public function shopCategories()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        Shop::class,
        business_categories::class,
        'shop_id', // Foreign key on the shop table...
        'business_category_id', // Foreign key on the business table...
        'id', // Local key on the shop table...
        'id' // Local key on the business table...
    );
}
```

Comment: business category is saperate independent table ,  fk from business_category and fk from shops go to shop_categories ,

Comment: I have posted my tables screenshot could you please check

Comment: try now I replaced `business_id` with `business_category_id`.

Comment: remember to replace `Shop::Class` and `business_categories::class` with your model names